# Get the next value from the minimum value in array

Tags: arrays, opencv, numpy, pixel

I have a image, it's a array. I want to get the value after minimum value, I wish you understand me because I dont speak english very well.
The minimum value in a pixel of this image is -3.40282e+38. I want to know the value that is after -3.40282e+38.

it must be for example 0.3 0.4..

I tried with image.min() but it print -3.40282e+38 .. I need the next value of that.

also I tried

```
 minimo = img.min()
for i in range(rows):
 for j in range(cols):
     for k in img[i,j]:
          if k> minimo:
               print k.min()
```

but I got this error

```
 TypeError: 'numpy.float32' object is not iterable
```

Comment: if the min value is `-3.40282e+38`, you probably have some errors :D

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find nth smallest element in numpy array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22546180/find-nth-smallest-element-in-numpy-array)

Comment: Does the array contain duplicate values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
import numpy as np
sorted_vec = np.unique(img.reshape(-1))
second_smallest = sorted_vec[1]
```

Comment: do you know how to count pixels ? I need to count the white pixels or elements of value 255.

Comment: @Yehadska If you have a new question, please ask a new question. But before that, please at least check the documentation, or other answers on SO.  You need to do at least a little research before posting a question. For example the solution for this one could have been found with a simple google search. Hint: you can use `countNonZero`

Comment: [`np.partition`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.partition.html) is a better option than `np.sort` for this.

Answer (score 1):

For large arrays, using `np.partition` will be much faster than sorting the array, as in [@dslack's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33897754/2937831):

```
import numpy as np
img = np.random.rand(1000, 1000)

# Compute via a full sort
np.unique(img.ravel())[1]
# 3.25658401967e-06

# Compute via a partition
np.partition(img.ravel(), 1)[1]
# 3.25658401967e-06
```

The two methods give the same results, and we can see that the partition approach is significantly faster:

```
%timeit np.unique(img.ravel())[1]
# 10 loops, best of 3: 86.8 ms per loop

%timeit np.partition(img.ravel(), 1)[1]
# 100 loops, best of 3: 4.99 ms per loop
```

The reason for the speed is that `partition` does not sort the full array, but simply swaps values until all smaller values are to the left of the given index, and all larger values are to the right.

Note that the results will differ if the minimum value is not unique – but it is not clear from your question which output you desire in this case.