# How to find nth minimum of a numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I want to find indices in ascending order of elements in last row in a 2D numpy array. An example is as below.

```
ti = np.array([[255, 2, 255, 9], [4, 255, 6, 255], [23, 11, 5, 18]])

# output = function(ti[-1])
# output : 2, 1, 3, 0
```

How do I achieve this? np.argmin only gives one minimum, and I could not find any other way including using partition (which returns sorted elements instead). Kindly help.

Comment: I believe this is a duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22546180/find-nth-smallest-element-in-numpy-array

Comment: What is "smaller" between `[255, 2, 255, 9]` and `[4, 255, 6, 255]`? How would you determine the "minimum"?

Comment: What does output `2, 1, 3, 0` denote exactly?

Comment: It's not at all clear what you're trying to do. You've got 4 numbers in the output, so you're not argsorting the rows. The numbers aren't right for argsorting the columns, or for taking the argmin of each column. I have no idea what that `2, 1, 3, 0` is supposed to be.

Comment: Are you trying to find the "nth minimum of a numpy array" as the title suggests or the " indices in ascending order" of all the elements as you wrote in the question?

Comment: hi, sorry for not being clear enough. i wanted to find the indices of minimums in ascending order in last row of the 2D array ti, that is  ti[-1]

Answer (score 0):

I tried np.argsort which sort of gives this output. Others please englighten if any more insights to be added.

```
np.argsort(ti[-1])
```

output:

```
array([2, 1, 3, 0], dtype=int64)
```